# Selenium Webdriver Python How do you wait for text of an element to appear after clicking a button and keep trying until text appears

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a html table of with some columns.  Each row shows the name of a report 
I can select a report and click the run button to process the reports.
The text "view" will appear in the View column after i click on the Reports button.
The "view" text will not appear on it's own.
It can be a few clicks until the text appears.
I want to keep clicking the Reports button until the "view" text appears

I think the best solution would be to put this in a while loop somehow.

I have tried but I get the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'element' referenced before assignment
```

Error Trace is:

```
    Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore\TestCases\ReportingPage_TestCase.py", line 81, in test_1_add_matches_report
    print reports_page.is_view_link_present_to_view_the_report("Matches")
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore\Pages\reports.py", line 321, in is_view_link_present_to_view_the_report
    view_element = self.get_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="reporting_reports_ct_fields_body"]//td[.//span[text()="%s"]]/following-sibling::td[2]//span[text()="view"]' % report_name)
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore\Pages\base.py", line 34, in get_element
    return element
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'element' referenced before assignment
```

The method with the While loop to wait for element to be found is:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
class ReportsPage(BasePage):

def __init__(self, d):
        super(ReportsPage, self).__init__(d)
        self.datamap_name = UsefulHelperMethods.read_from_file("datamap_name")
        self.tool_bar = ToolbarPage(self.driver)

def is_view_link_present_to_view_the_report(self, report_name):
            # Params : report_name : Name of the report which to select to view
            table_id = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'reporting_reports_ct_fields_body')))
            found = False
            while not found:
                try:
                    view_element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="reporting_reports_ct_fields_body"]//td[.//span[text()="%s"]]/following-sibling::td[2]//span[text()="view"]' % report_name)
                    found = True
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    time.sleep(2)
                    self.tool_bar.click_reports_button_from_toolbar()
```

get element defined in my Base Class is:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


class BasePage(object):

def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(120)


# returns the element if found
    def get_element(self, how, what):
        # params how: By locator type
        # params what: locator value
        try:
            element = self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e:
            print what
            print "Element not found "
            print e
        return element
```

My TestCase class which calls the method is:

```
    from Menus.project_navigator import ProjectNavigatorPage
    from Menus.toolbar import ToolbarPage
    from Pages.reports import ReportsPage

    class ReportingPage_TestCase(BaseTestCase):

        def test_1_add_matches_report(self):
            tool_bar = ToolBarPage(self.driver)
            project_navigator = ProjectNavigatorPage(self.driver)
            reports_page = project_navigator.select_projectNavigator_item("Reports")
            reports_page.click_add_button_for_reports()
            reports_page.select_a_report_checkbox_from_reports_page("Matches")
            reports_page.click_run_button_to_run_the_report()
            reports_page.click_ok_from_reports_dialog()
            tool_bar.click_reports_button_from_toolbar()
            print reports_page.is_view_link_present_to_view_the_report("Matches")
```

How can I keep clicking on the reports button (say every 2 secs) and check if the "view" text is present.  Keep trying for about 5 mins.
If at the end of 5 mins it still does not find the view link then to print view text not found, test failed?
I don't want to use time.sleep as that is not effient.  The view text could appear in few seconds or a minute depening on how large the report is.

Thanks, help appreciated.
Riaz

The HTML is:

```
<table id="reporting_reports_ct_fields_body" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
<colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="GLKP2TGBFG GLKP2TGBMG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
            <td class="GLKP2TGBEG GLKP2TGBGG GLKP2TGBHG GLKP2TGBNG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-7232" style="outline-style:none;" tabindex="0">
                    <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GLKP2TGBEG GLKP2TGBGG GLKP2TGBNG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-7233" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="linkhover" title="Matches" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">Matches</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GLKP2TGBEG GLKP2TGBGG GLKP2TGBNG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-7234" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="manual" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">manual</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GLKP2TGBEG GLKP2TGBGG GLKP2TGBNG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-7235" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="linkhover block" title="view" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">view</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GLKP2TGBEG GLKP2TGBGG GLKP2TGBNG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-7236" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="Matches report" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">Matches report</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GLKP2TGBEG GLKP2TGBGG GLKP2TGBNG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-7237" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="USN entities" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">USN entities</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GLKP2TGBEG GLKP2TGBGG GLKP2TGBNG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-7238" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="05/11/2015 15:24:47" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">05/11/2015 15:24:47</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GLKP2TGBEG GLKP2TGBGG GLKP2TGBNG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-7239" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="block" title="" style="">12</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GLKP2TGBEG GLKP2TGBGG GLKP2TGBBH GLKP2TGBNG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-7240" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="INFOSHARE\riaz.ladhani" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">COMPANY\riaz.ladhani</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="GLKP2TGBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

element only exists in your try block you must define it outside of a try block. In pseudo code it would look like:

```
try
{
   var element;
}
...
return element; // but does not exist in this scope here
```

just return it in your try and you're fine, no need for the extra line:

```
    try:
        return self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
    except NoSuchElementException, e:
        print what
        print "Element not found "
        print e
    return None
```

to continously click the button you can use WebDriverWait (you need to return `None` if the element was not found in your `get_element` for this to work).

create a new method that will click and check for the element

```
def clickTillView:
   reportElement.click()
   return get_element(self, how, what) != None
```

then you can wait for clickTillView to be true ergo the element exists

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10000, 1, None).until(clickTillView(), "view was not found in time")
```

Forgive my Python mistakes, I'm a Java guy :p but this is basically how you can solve it.

Comment: Also I want to keep clicking the reports button until the "View" element is found. Every 2 secs click the reports button and check if View text is found.  After about a count of 100 clicks if not found then raise an exception.  How do i do this with the while loop?  Thanks

Comment: either you use the implicit wait of webdriver, which will wait a given amount of time for an element to exist, or you use the `WebDriverWait` which I would recommed (see in the edited example above)